# FATAL EXCEPTION saving/restoring instance for Android HTML application state

Tags: android, cordova, instance, savestate

I am attempting to grasp the simple aspect of saving an Android application and restoring it on resume.  I have surfed all over for the answer but nothing works.  Since I am having trouble with the app that I am developing I have boiled it down to the test app below.  I am getting a null pointer somewhere.  I have a basic HTML page that I load.  When I rotate the phone it attempts to save but does not restore properly.  What am I missing here?

**This is my activity:**

```
package com.example.saverestore;

import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init();

    if(savedInstanceState == null || savedInstanceState.isEmpty())
    {
        Log.d("RGiTest", "super.loadUrl");
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d("RGiTest", "Restoring the state");
        this.appView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
   super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
   this.appView.saveState(outState);
}

}
```

**This is my index.html:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Save Restore</title>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: #000000">
    <h1 style="margin-left: 40px; color: #FF0000;">Test Save/Restore</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**I get this error when I rotate the phone:**

```
01-31 14:18:31.707: D/DroidGap(3129): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
01-31 14:18:31.726: D/Cordova(3129): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
01-31 14:20:15.183: D/AndroidRuntime(3129): Shutting down VM
01-31 14:20:15.183: W/dalvikvm(3129): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
01-31 14:20:15.246: E/AndroidRuntime(3129): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 14:20:15.246: E/AndroidRuntime(3129): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-31 14:20:15.246: E/AndroidRuntime(3129):     at java.lang.String.indexOf(String.java:1145)
01-31 14:20:15.246: E/AndroidRuntime(3129):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.loadUrlNow(CordovaWebView.java:517)
01-31 14:20:15.246: E/AndroidRuntime(3129):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.loadUrl(CordovaWebView.java:402)
01-31 14:20:15.246: E/AndroidRuntime(3129):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient.onPageFinished(CordovaWebViewClient.java:298)
01-31 14:20:15.246: E/AndroidRuntime(3129):     at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:282)
01-31 14:20:15.246: E/AndroidRuntime(3129):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-31 14:20:15.246: E/AndroidRuntime(3129):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-31 14:20:15.246: E/AndroidRuntime(3129):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
01-31 14:20:15.246: E/AndroidRuntime(3129):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 14:20:15.246: E/AndroidRuntime(3129):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-31 14:20:15.246: E/AndroidRuntime(3129):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
01-31 14:20:15.246: E/AndroidRuntime(3129):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
01-31 14:20:15.246: E/AndroidRuntime(3129):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can someone offer advice or direction on this?

Thanks

Comment: phonegap Google Group Discussion:https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/9i09M5sPNXM

Comment: What do you have set for the configChanges of your main activity in the manifest?

Comment: Thanks Simon you solved it.  I googled that and added the following to my manifest and it solved it: android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden